# Get values of a string if the other string values contain a yes

Tags: php, string, comparison

```
if ( isset($_POST['figuresugsubjectposition'])) {
    $figuresubject_taxonomies = array( 'figuresugsubjectposition' => $_POST['figuresugsubjectposition']);
    $figuresubject_taxonomies_from = array( 'figuresugsubjectfrom' => $_POST['figuresugsubjectfrom']);
    foreach ( $figuresubject_taxonomies_from as $tax_name_from => $terms_from ) {
        $figuresubject_taxonomies_from = $terms_from;
    }
    //this will return: Blue, White, Green, Yellow, Black.. etc

    foreach ( $figuresubject_taxonomies as $tax_name => $terms ) {
        $figuresubject_taxonomies = $terms;
    }
    //this will return: yes, yes, no, yes, yes.. etc
}
```

I want `$figuresubject_taxonomies_fnl` to have only those colors who have a "yes" in the second string. In the example above, `$figuresubject_taxonomies_fnl` shall echo: Blue, White, Yellow, Black...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind losing the original keys in the array, you can do this:

```
<?php
$colours = array('black', 'orange', 'yellow');
$yes_no = array('yes', 'no', 'yes');

$combined = array_combine($colours, $yes_no);
$filtered = array_filter($combined, function($x) { return $x === 'yes'; });

$result = array_keys($filtered));
```

Now `$result` will be this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => black
    [1] => yellow
)
```

`array_combined` returns a new array, made from an array of keys (your colours) and an array of values ('yes' or 'no'). `array_filter` returns only the elements for which the callback function returns `true`.

Alternatively, you could just use a loop:

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($colours); ++$i) {
    if ($yes_no[$i] === 'yes') $result[] = $colours[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've checked the first method. That's exactly what I wanted. I will check the the other method and reply accordingly.